# How exit from aws batch docker with error code?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-batch

Just **for testing purposes** what to exec to fail docker in aws batch with custom code?

I have tried:

- exit 137 -> `CannotStartContainerError: API error (404): oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"exit\": executable file not found in $PATH"`
- Exit 137
- bash exit 137 -> `bash: exit: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

#### Assuming you are trying with busy box you can use any one of below format

Space delimited: `sh -c 'exit 1'`

Json: `["sh","-c","exit 1"]`